# Postgis/Postgres - ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm completely new to postgis/postgres and trying to construct a trigger to update a field in a table containing road extent polygons(lsg_maintainance_responsibility) with the length of the related centre line, contained in another table(lsg_esu_lines).

The trigger function:

```
DECLARE g integer;

BEGIN

g:=NEW.esu_id;
UPDATE gazetteer.lsg_maintainance_responsibility a
    SET poly_length= ST_Length(b.geometry) from lsg_esu_lines b
    inner join lsg_maintainance_responsibility on a.esu_id = b.esu_id
    WHERE a.type='Carriageway' and a.esu_id = g;
RETURN NEW;
```

fails with the "ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table a"

From reading other posts, is it because the join clause is executed first in which case it would clearly not know what a is?  Trouble is due to my lack of sql skills everything I try to fix it just causes another error.

Thanks

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504269/postgis-postgres-error-invalid-reference-to-from-clause-entry-for-table-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use joins in the [update](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) this way, but replacing the join with a where clause should work:

```
UPDATE gazetteer.lsg_maintainance_responsibility a
  SET poly_length = ST_Length(b.geometry) 
  FROM lsg_esu_lines b
  WHERE 
   a.esu_id = b.esu_id 
   AND a.type='Carriageway' 
   AND a.esu_id = g;
RETURN NEW;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f55a4/20)

Comment: You beat me too it. Update, set, from, where is the order in Postgres.